# Checking dynamic arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I cannot realise what needs to happen with the following code...

There are two arrays. *potentialFirstQ_array* takes the number of the question, while *correspondingNum* is the amount of times the user has got said question correct.

The following is to check whether all the questions have the same *correspondingNum*, if this was different then the Question where the user has got it more correct than the lowest value is removed from the list.
So, the questions displayed are the ones the user has gotten correct, the least.

So, the list is constantly changing size, the current issue is that the size is out of range. I have tried various options, but I reverted the code back to its simplest state.

My code is as follows:

```
for i in range(0,int(size)):
    size1=len(potentialFirstQ_array)
    for x in range(0,int(size1)):
        if lowest != "0":
            if int(correspondingNum[x]) > int(lowest):
                x=x-change_in_size
                potentialFirstQ_array.pop(x)
            else:
                if correspondingNum[x] != lowest:
                    x=x-change_in_size
                    potentialFirstQ_array.pop(x)
```

Any clarity is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `min()`.

```
lowest = min(correspondingNum)
questionsLowest = []
for i in range(len(potentialFirstQ_array)):
    if correspondingNum[i] = lowest:
        questionsLowest.append(potentialFirstQ_array[i])
```